# How to run code every minute when app is closed(terminated)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send a request for checking if there is anything new for user to do **When the app is closed**.

##### for example:

we have this code.

```dart
http.MultipartRequest request =
        http.MultipartRequest(requestMethod, Uri.parse(url))
          ..headers.addAll(headers)
          ..fields.addAll(fields);

http.StreamedResponse response;
response = await request.send().timeout(kTimeOutDuration);
```

I want to this code to be execute every minutes and get the response when app is **closed**.

Comment: I think once your app is terminated, you're not running any code.  You can respond to wake up from a notification, but that's about your only choice.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Using Notifications.  Too much info for a SO response comment. :)  Google for "flutter notifications"